# Switch Language Session not working on mobiles

Tags: php, session, multilingual

I am using Sessions to remember users language choice.
Working fine on PC browsers, however not working on mobiles. It changes my languages when they click the flag, but when refresh or move to other page language is back to english.
Any idea why?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('lang/'. $_GET['lang'] . '.php')) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
} 
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en'; // default value
}
include('lang/'. $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php'); // include lang file
```

thats my code.

Comment: check whether you have  starting sessions in other pages.

Comment: I do. and they are working fine on desktop. only on mobiles it doesn't.
have the same code on each of my other pages.

Comment: Please share the code where it does not work. That will make it easy to compare. I think the language switch is only working when the parameter is set. That probably explains when the user click on flag which perhaps has parameter in the link.

Comment: http://hublaalike.com
please check it.